# What are "Centipede" and "Greedy Roach"?

Tags: mice-and-mystics

Just played Mice and Mystics for the first time and we had a few issues with spawning monsters with encounters. Specifically, we had two monsters spawned my encounters that we were not 100% sure what they were.

- "Centipede" had no initiative card, so we assumed that the "Cave Centipede" initiative card was correct (and we couldn't find any references to Cave Centipedes anywhere after a quick search)
- "Greedy Roach" had no initiative card, so we assumed that the "Roach" initiative card was correct (but "Roach" is also referenced on encounter cards)

Are these substitutions correct, or are we missing initiative cards?

Comment: This thread states that there are [19 Initiative cards](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/12490690#12490690). There are Initiative cards for "Roach" and "Centipede", but not for those *adjective* versions. My guess is that the storybook is modifying the normal rules for those encounters, for example the [Sample Storybook](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/mice-and-mystics/mmstorybook.pdf) has **Hungry Roaches** (page 5) that have a Special Rule that breaks the normal actions a Roach would take (they eat cheese instead of moving closer to the Heroes)

Comment: The issues described are not with storybook related minions, just normal minions spawned by encounter cards.

Comment: Standard 9 encounter cards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, those are the correct Inititive cards**

From the rulebook (page 15, or [17 of the PDF](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/mice-and-mystics/mmrulebook.pdf))

> **Greedy Roaches**
>
> Some encounters include ’greedy roaches‘. **Greedy roaches use the same initiative card as normal roaches**. When greedy roaches are placed on the board, all roaches in play become greedy roaches. When a greedy roach steals a cheese from a mouse, that cheese is placed on the minion cheese wheel on the story control board.

[Jerry Hawthorne](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamedesigner/23005/jerry-hawthorne) the [Mice and Mystics'](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/games/mice-and-mystics) game designer, said in [this thread to the question](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/10375292#10375292):

> Q: When you fill the cheese wheel and a surge occurs, if the surge on the encounter card is a Centipede, which initiative card do you use? There doesn't seem to be a 'normal' centipede card - and there are two to choose from. Which one is used? They both appear to be 'named' centipedes with different special abilities and stats.
>
> A: **Use the Cave Centipede card.**